# Sharepoint User groups

Tags: permissions, user-accounts

I have a Sharepoint 2010 portal set up with custom user groups like ManagerUserGroup, SubManagerUserGroup etc. When I add any new user to those User groups, that user gets an 'Access denied' error message upon login to portal.

What I noticed is that if I add this user to standard user group (i.e. Visitor, Members, Owners) that user can login successfully. I don't want to add users to standard user groups before adding them to custom user groups for access, as it defeats the purpose.

Can anyone help me in ignoring the standard user groups in this case? Or am I missing something here? Please note: I have given Site permissions to Custom User groups as well.

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign your group permissions to allow your users access to the site.

You can set permission levels like readers, contributors or full control (among others) which will decide what users of the group will have access to.

You can also setup site groups to decide which groups will be the owner/member/visitor groups, under site permissions.

Answer (score 0):

By default three groups are associated with SharePoint Site, (Site Owners, Site Members, Site Visitors) . So those groups had a permissions associated with the Site.

But the custom groups you have created, didn't had a permissions to the Site. So that those users added to the groups gets "Access Denied" error.

So Ensure those groups had a permissions on those sites. If not, add the permissions to the groups.

Answer (score 0):

I added the permission to group while creating itself and added the user in to it. But still the user is not logged in to the site.

Anybody has other solution?

Thanks
Abraham